# How can I get totals from array of objects with string values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, recharts

**Input:**

```
[
  {
    15: "3.0",
    20: "6.0",
    34: "4.0,
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    27: "6.0",
    32: "4.0,
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "",
    23: "12.0",
    44: "7.0,
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    70: "6.0",
    54: "34.0,
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
]
```

I am trying to reordening some data, because I need to do a Pie Chart in **JavaScript**.

I did something but going through many processes and maybe there is a better way to do this

This is my actual data (similar):

I need just the totals of the whole data per dosis and sex.
I also need to change the "string number" to number.

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    totalFirstMale: 13
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    totalSecondMale: 13
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    totalFirstFemale: 19
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
  {
    totalSecondFemale: 43
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
]
```

PD:
The object key value means the age, but I just need the total per sex.

The original array contains 4 key sex (male, female, unknown, intersex) with same structure.

I tried something like this:

```
    const maleData= json.filter(el => el.Sex === 'Male')
    const femaleData= json.filter(el => el.Sex === 'Female')

    const dataMaleFirst = maleData[0]
    const dataMaleSecond = maleData[1]
    const dataFemaleFirst = femaleData[0]
    const dataFemaleSecond = femaleData[1]

    const objValueFirstMale = Object.values(dataMaleFirst).map(el => el * 1)
    const objValueSecondMale = Object.values(dataMaleSecond).map(el => el * 1)

    const objValueFirstFemale = Object.values(dataFemaleFirst).map(el => el * 1)
    const objValueSecondFemale = Object.values(dataFemaleSecond).map(el => el * 1)

    let totalFirstMale = 0
    let totalSecondMale = 0
    let totalFirstFemale = 0
    let totalSecondFemale = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < objValueFirstMale.length || i < objValueSegundasHombre.length; i++) {
        !isNaN(objValueFirstMale[i]) ? totalFirstMale += objValueFirstMale[i] : 0
        !isNaN(objValueSecondMale[i]) ? totalSecondMale += objValueSecondMale[i] : 0
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < objValueFirstFemale.length || i < objValueSecondFemale.length; i++) {
        !isNaN(objValueFirstFemale[i]) ? totalFirstFemale += objValueFirstFemale[i] : 0
        !isNaN(objValueSecondFemale[i]) ? totalSecondFemale += objValueSecondFemale[i] : 0
    }
    
    return {
        firstMaleDosis: totalFirstMale,
        secondMaleDosis: totalSecondMale,
        totalMaleDosis: totalFirstMale + totalSecondMale,
        firstFemaleDosis: totalFirstFemale,
        secondFemaleDosis: totalSecondFemale ,
        totalFemaleDosis: totalFirstFemale + totalSecondFemale 
    }
```

It Looks terrible I know hahahaha and now I have to add unknown data & intersex data. So it could be problematic to do all this "logic" again >_>.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post some code.

Comment: You can't do math with strings so you have to convert them into numbers first. How you would do that would depend on the programming language you're using, which you've not indicated with any of the tags that you used.

Comment: So sorry. I'm using JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I did this:**

```
let output = data.map(({ Dosis, Sex, ...restOfData }) => {
    const countedKey = Object.keys(restOfData)
    
    let totalCount = 0

    countedKey.forEach(el => {
        totalCount += +restOfData[el]
    })

    return {
        Dosis,
        Sex,
        [`total${Dosis}${Sex}`]: totalCount
    }
})
```

Thanks you all for to clear my doubts !!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't mention which language are you using.
This solution is for javascript.

```
 const data = [
  {
    15: "3.0",
    20: "6.0",
    34: "4.0",
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    27: "6.0",
    32: "4.0",
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "",
    23: "12.0",
    44: "7.0",
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    70: "6.0",
    54: "34.0",
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
]
  const output = data.map(el => {
    const countedKey = Object.keys(el).filter(item => !['Dosis', 
    'Sex'].includes(item));
    let totalCount = 0;
    countedKey.forEach(cnt => {
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(el[cnt]))) totalCount += parseInt(el[cnt]);
    });
    return { [`total${el.Dosis}${el.Sex}`]: totalCount, Dosis: el.Dosis, Sex: 
   el.Sex }
  });

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yes I'm using JavaScript. Thank you! I will prove it your method, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can try out with this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    15: "3.0",
    20: "6.0",
    34: "4.0",
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    27: "6.0",
    32: "4.0",
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Male"
  },
  {
    15: "",
    23: "12.0",
    44: "7.0",
    Dosis: "First",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
  {
    15: "3.0",
    70: "6.0",
    54: "34.0",
    Dosis: "Second",
    Sex: "Female"
  },
];
let output = [];
data.forEach(e => {

  const tempElem = {...e};
  delete tempElem['Dosis'];
  delete tempElem['Sex'];
  output.push({
    Dosis: e['Dosis'],
    Sex: e['Sex'],
    [`total${e.Dosis}${e.Sex}`]: Object.values(tempElem).filter(e => e !== '').reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0)
  });
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try with this =)